# GCC Relative Search Directory

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, cl

I trying to use MinGW GCC instead of MSVC compiler. I have an issue concerning the GCC search directory.
I will describe my issue in a simple example.

I have some file: `C:\Project\Module1\Module1.c` that contains:

```
#include "Module2.h"
```

, where `Module2.h` is in: `C:\Project\Module2\Module2.h`

To compile `Module1.c`, I use:

> gcc -I..\Module2\ C:\Project\Module1\Module1.c

But it gives an error: `Module2.h no such file or directory`.
I also tried to use :

```
cd C:\Project\Module2\
```

before it, but I get the same error.

Comment: My example above works fine. But I was not implementing is correctly. I need to delete this question.

Answer (score 1):

The paths you add are relative from your *current* working directory. So if you're in `C:\Project` you need to add `-IModule2`.

Comment: Why do you say "So if you're in C:\Project" ?

Comment: @HeshamEraqi Because the path you add is relative *from where you are running the compiler*.

Comment: You assume that I use `cd C:\Project\` ?

Comment: @HeshamEraqi Then read my answer again, as it's the situation I describe and show what to do.

Comment: OK. I got you. I got confused because that I use cd C:\Project\Module2\

Comment: My example above works fine. But I was not implementing is correctly.
I need to delete this question.